# Ktor WebSockets: kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Serializer for class 'DefaultClientWebSocketSession' is not found

Tags: kotlin, ktor, ktor-client

today I was on the way to make a real-time Application and I wanted to use WebSockets for updateing my states.

Everything worked well until I got this Exception:

```
kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Serializer for class 'DefaultClientWebSocketSession' is not found.
Mark the class as @Serializable or provide the serializer explicitly.
```

I searched and searched and I didn't find anything.

So my code looks simliar to this:

Gradle Imports:

```
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:1.6.2")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:1.6.2")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:1.6.2")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-websockets:1.6.2")
```

Code:

```
suspend fun main() {
    val endpoint = Url("http://localhost:8080")
    val client = HttpClient(CIO) {
        install(JsonFeature) {
            serializer = KotlinxSerializer()
        }
        install(WebSockets)
    }
    client.webSocket({
        url {
            takeFrom(endpoint)
            path("beeam")
        }
    }) {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

I hope there is somebody out there who can help me.

Comment: Could you please try to replace `http` protocol with `ws` in the URL of an endpoint? Also, please share a setup for a server.

Comment: Thanks that helped! The problem was the scheme. But the execption text had really nothing to do with the scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**

The Problem is that `endpoint.protocol` is `URLProtocol.HTTP` and not `URLProtocol.WS` and with `takeFrom` you also transfer this property.

**Solution**

```
suspend fun main() {
    val endpoint = Url("http://localhost:8080")
    val client = HttpClient(CIO) {
        install(JsonFeature) {
            serializer = KotlinxSerializer()
        }
        install(WebSockets)
    }
    client.webSocket({
        url {
            takeFrom(endpoint)
            path("beeam")
            protocol = URLProtocol.WS
        }
    }) {
        //Do something
    }
}
```